# PHP $_POST Undefined index but var_dump works

Tags: php, post

when I do

```
var_dump($_POST);
```

I have the following result :

```
'apk' => string 'apk_techs.apk' (length=13)
```

which is what I'm expecting, but when I do

```
readFile("./".$_POST['apk']);
```

it throws the following error

```
[09-Jun-2017 10:14:00 UTC] PHP Warning:  readfile(./): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\wamp64\www\atawa_api\api_techs.php on line 848
```

Can someone tell me about somthing I would ignore ?

**EDIT**

The path is correct and it is only for debugging, the problem isn't that path is incorrect or not found, but not given (considering the undefined index).

Comment: You are missing a `'`.

Comment: assuming the missing quotation mark was a typo then I'd suggest using the full path to the file rather than a relative one

Comment: It clearly says, apk file doesn't exists on specified path. Either your apk file and your php file must be in a same folder or give the full apk path in readFile

Comment: @TomUdding Thanks but I wasn't in my code

Comment: @pravindot17 not at all, "./"+ $_POST['apk'] just returns "./" because it throws "undefined index".

Answer (score 0):

for readfile function you have to pass the complete path of file.
eg like below  : readFile("/var/www/tttt.apk");

Comment: Actually I don't, when I type "./apk_techs.apk" it works fine